# C# Unable to loop through control collection and set properties on a user control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, user-controls, controlcollection

Hi I have a Forms application that uses a custom control based on a Track bar called colorSlider.  This control was obtained from code project and added to the tools in VS2017.  All aspects of the control work fine.  I can change any properties as I wish.  However, the final project is quite large and all of the track bars (50 or so) will be replaced with this custom control.  I also want to be able to modify the look and feel of the sliders with user customization skins.
So, here is a typical command to change button on the slider.

```
colorSlider1.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
```

And this works perfectly fine.  However I want to do this in a loop.  All controls are on a panel called backpanel.  Here is an example for changing the forecolor of a button:

```
        foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }
```

This works great.  However, if I try this:

```
        foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
            {
                if (c is ColorSlider.ColorSlider)
                {
                    c.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this case visual studio gives a syntax error

Error   CS1061  'Control' does not contain a definition for 'ThumbInnerColor' and no accessible extension method 'ThumbInnerColor' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So anyone have an idea on how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or in newer C#

```
foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ColorSlider.ColorSlider s)
        {
            s.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the Controls.OfType<> option:

```
        foreach(Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            foreach(ColorSlider cs in pnl.Controls.OfType<ColorSlider>())
            {
                cs.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
            }
        }
```

Comment: VS doesn't understand .OfType  as written.

Comment: Works perfectly for me...not sure where it went wrong.

Comment: nice, i wasnt aware of the OfType.. that will come in handy

Answer (score 2):

look at the error.. 
*Control' does not contain a definition for 'ThumbInnerColor'* .. which is true.. *Control* does not contain that property.
now look at your code:

```
c.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
```

you are trying to set the property on a *Object* which is type *Control*..
that property belongs to a specific control of type *ColorSlider*..

the fix should be as easy as casting the *Control* to *ColorSlider*

```
foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
        {
            ColorSlider.ColorSlider slider = c as ColorSlider.ColorSlider;
            if (slider != null)
            {
                slider.ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ColorSlider.ColorSlider)
            {
                (c as ColorSlider.ColorSlider).ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
foreach (Panel pnl in backPanel.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control c in pnl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ColorSlider.ColorSlider)
            {
                ((ColorSlider.ColorSlider)c).ThumbInnerColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 130, 208);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: youre welcome. they are all the same thing, just different way of doing it. you should look-up type casting in .NET. the first way will give null if control is not the type we want. the second way would throw a null exception if the control was not the right type. the third way would throw a invalid cast exception if the control was wrong type. but the type was already tested before hand, so exception should never occur.